# Connect Raspberry Pi Model 1b, Kuman 3.5 inch TFT LCD and Circus Logic Audio Card

Tags: audio, display

I got

- a Kuman 3.5 inch 320*480 Resolution Touch Screen TFT LCD
- the Circus Logic Audio Card (https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card) and
- a Rasperry Pi (2011.12) (http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/raspberry_pi_model_b_rev2_01.jpg)

Is it possible to connect both the audio card and the display to the rasperry pi? What happens to the Video Out already included into the rasperry pi.

Thanks! Dominik